# Concat and join to display sum and max for classes of all in database

Tags: sql

```
    SELECT concat(faculty.facfirstname,',', faculty.faclastname), faculty.idfaculty, offering.offterm, course.coursedesc, offering.capacity 
from offering
inner join faculty on offering.faculty_idFaculty= faculty.idfaculty 
inner join course on offering.course_idcourse= course.idcourse
order by course.coursedesc ASC;
```

My SQL does not show anything, but this is how I want my columns to look.
I want my rows to display facultyid, facultyname, largest capacity of courses, sum capacity of classes , number of classes each teacher is teaching

Comment: Poor error handling? Your query has a syntax error.

Comment: It doesn't show a syntax error it just doesn't show any rows.

Comment: Your query still is invalid. (Or is it a copy-and-paste issue?) There's a missing `)` at the end of the select list.

Comment: Show us some sample table data, and the expected result, all as formatted text (no images.) Simplified! [mcve]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: If the query runs but does not return anything, that means that there (at least) one table does not contain any rows. Or that the join condition does not find any matches. Do you get a result if you change the `inner join` to a `left join`?